# How do you return the latest value in an Excel list with blank cells in the middle?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tried a couple of formulae to try and get the most recent value in a row as per the below but without success - only seems to work when the data has no blanks??

[image]

Comment: can you share the current formula you are using.. ?

Comment: You mean to say the Highest Value?

Comment: =IF(OFFSET(E20,0,MATCH(MAX(E20:P20)+1,E20:P20,1)-1)>0,OFFSET(E20,0,MATCH(MAX(E20:P20)+1,E20:P20,1)-1),"A")

Comment: No - most recent not highest.   The "A" was simply to avoid blank return so I could see when evaluating the formula

Comment: @Ross Barnes,, you mean to say the last entered value in Range `E20:P20`?

Comment: Yes - in this case in Dec (P20) - but it does not work in row 19

Comment: @Ross Barnes,, I got you want Month Name (as Header) for the Column where the last  value is been filled ,, write?

Comment: I actually want to identify the value of the number in the last filled cell rather than the Month Name (but all the others have formulae in not values)

Answer (score 1):

*On the basis of the conversation between us **through comments**, I would like to suggest you a method will first find the **Last Entry** and then after finds the **corresponding Column Header**.*

[image]

1. Write this Formula to get the **Last Entered Value in Row**, in Cell `F3` & fill it Down.

   ```
   =LOOKUP(2,1/(A3:E3<>""),A3:E3)
   ```
2. To get the **corresponding Column Header** enter this Array Formula in Cell `G3`,
   finish it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> & fill Down.

   ```
   {=INDEX($A$1:$E$1,MAX(IF($A$3:$E$5=F3,COLUMN($A$3:$E$5)-COLUMN(A1)+1)))}
   ```

**N.B.**

- I've used two different Formulas Because basically you want to get the **Lats Entered Value** and getting the **Header Name** is an optional.
- *Adjust cell references in the Formula as you needed.*

Comment: the 2nd line formula does not work - it fails immediately on the $A$3:$F$5=F3 which returns #VALUE

Comment: @RossBarnes,, it's an Array Formula hope you have fished it with CSE 'Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. Do it properly will work!! ☺

Comment: @RossBarnes,, this `$A$3:$F$5=F3` has little correction,, it should like `$A$3:$E$5=F3` ☺

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking at this for some time and I have not been able to reproduce the answers when I use different data, the problem being that `LOOKUP()` requires the look-up vector to be sorted, which is not the questioner's case.

Using reduced data (to save typing) I used 5 rows of 5 columns:-

[image: Last cell]

For clarity I have built up the formulae over 3 columns:-

```
[G3]  =SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISBLANK(A3:E3))*2^COLUMN(A3:E3))
[H3]  =INT(LOG(G3,2))
[I3]  =OFFSET(A3,0,H3-1)
```

Then `G3:H3` are copied down the number of rows required.

Notes:-

- `G3` is a bit map of which cells have data.
- `H3` is the highest power of 2 in the bit map.
- `I3` is the contents of the last cell with data.
- The formulae can be nested, eg the last column number could be `=INT(LOG(SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISBLANK(A3:E3))*2^COLUMN(A3:E3)),2))`
- I developed this with LibreOffice, and tested it with Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Since the values in the range are numeric, you can use simply:

```
=LOOKUP(9.9E+307,$E11:$P11)
```

Since `lookup_value` will be higher than any value in the row, the formula will return the last numeric value in that row.

If you want to return the month name, then put that row in for the `result_vector` argument.

```
=LOOKUP(9.9E+307,$E11:$P11,$E$10:$P$10)
```

If the row is longer than `E:P`, adjust the parameter accordingly.

If the last column you want might contain text, then try:

```
=LOOKUP(2, 1/LEN($E11:$P11),$E11:$P11)
```

I think `HELP` for the `LOOKUP` function is incorrect.  See my correction:

*If the LOOKUP function can't find the lookup_value, the function matches the <s>largest</s>  **last** value in lookup_vector that is less than or equal to lookup_value.*